# 16.04 regularly fails to boot properly

Tags: boot

The computer will start, but gets stuck on a [black/purple screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp21a.jpg) before reaching the login screen. It is completely unresponsive, and needs a forced restart. This happens maybe half of all boots and has been going on for a couple of months. There's no pattern I can see.

After reboot, either the computer start normally, OR ubuntu runs some sort of diagnostic, black screen white text. It says something about "Recovering journal" and then "Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed". After rebooting again it starts up normally.

After booting successfully there are no problems whatsoever. The problem also occurs while waking up from hibernation.

- fsck from recovery mode, no errors.
- 3 passes with memtest86, no errors.
- SMART says disk is OK.

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, have you installed a driver in Windows to allow reading/writing to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? If so, disable it asap, as it's corrupting your Ubuntu partition. Then run a manual fsck, and you should be fine.

Comment: I don't dual boot, used to be a windows machine though. I ran a manual fsck and it returned no errors.

Comment: What does SMART have to say about your disk drive? I'd go to memtest86.com and download the free memory test and run at least one full pass.